# Using getText() with more than one parameter in Struts 2 and JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2, properties-file, dynamic-variables

I am working on the Struts2 framework with JSP. I have in my **.properties* file:

```
hover_remove=Remove access to {0} at {1}`
```

I have in my JSP, within a submit tag:

```
title="%{getText('hover_remove', new String[]{{appLabel}, {locationLabel}})}"
```

which would work in Java, but I'm getting the following error in JSP:

```
/WEB-INF/pages/admin/cm/view.jsp(9,287) 
JSPG0055E: Unable to create an xml attribute from name
```

Any tips for using `getText(String, List String[])` in JSP?

Comment: `String`? What string? `some_cool_package.String` or `java.lang.String`? Hint: there is hint in the question. :)

Comment: @AleksandrM thank you! It's showing the value now. However, instead of "Remove access to first at second" its showing "Remove access to [first] at [second]". Is it possible to remove the square brackets? When I test with just one: `"%{getText('hover_remove', {appLabel})}"` it shows correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create array of String-s then you need to use FQN for the class and remove not needed braces.

```
title="%{getText('hover_remove', new java.lang.String[]{appLabel, locationLabel})}"
```

BUT you can use `getText` method which accepts `List` as the second argument and take advantage of OGNL list creation feature. In OGNL to create a list you need to simple put a list of expressions in curly braces.

```
title="%{getText('hover_remove', {appLabel, locationLabel})}"
```

Comment: It was the extra brackets. Thank you!